# Ordenar arreglo en Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Estoy obteniendo un array desde una base de datos (en orden descendente) y los pinto en el front en una tabla y en un grafico como se muestra en la imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero en la parte de la grafica quiero ordenalo de forma ascendente y hago lo siguiente:

```
export class PruebasComponent implements OnInit {

  data: any[];
  dataSource: PeriodicElement[] = [];
  lineChartData: ChartDataSets[];
    .......
 ngOnInit() {
    this.loading = true;


    this.datos.getDesktopLimit().subscribe(
      res => {
        this.loading = false;
        this.data = [res];
        this.dataSource = this.data[0]; //aqui almaceno el arreglo y lo paso al componente html
        this.barChartData = true;
        this.getFilter(this.dataSource); // ejecuto la funcion getFilter()
      }
    )
  }
```

con un sort lo ordeno de forma ascendente para pasarlo a la grafica

```
  getFilter(data) {
    console.log(data);

     data.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id); //ordenar de forma ascendente para la grafica

    for (let entry of data) {
      this.date.push(moment(entry.created).format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm'))
      this.time.push(entry.total_load_time * 0.001)
    }

    this.lineChartData =  [{ data: this.time, label: 'Time Render' }];
    this.lineChartLabels = this.date;
    this.loading = false
  }
```

**Efectivamente me lo ordena pero la tabla tambien se ordena de forma ascendente**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas teniendo un problema de referencia, en javascript (TS también), todos los objetos pasan por referencia. Tienes que separar los dos objetos: tabla y gráfica.

Entonces:

```
let dataOriginalDB:any[] = []; // Tu arreglo de objetos 
let dataParaTabla:any[] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(dataOriginalDB)) //deep Copy
let dataParaGrafica:any[] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(dataOriginalDB)) //deep Copy
```

Ahora cuando haga un sort no se te van a cambiar los otros automático, la idea es que al pasarlo a string y luego a JSON de nuevo pierda la referencia.

hacerlo con JSON.parse es lo mas seguro, depende de cuanta profundidad tengan tus objetos (objetos dentro de objetos).

Otras formas de hacer copias de objectos y evitar la referencia son con `Object.assign()` y el operador spread `...`

```
let dataOriginalDB:any[] = []; // Tu arreglo de objetos 
let dataParaTabla:any[] = { ... dataOriginalDB } //deep Copy con spread
let dataParaGrafica:any[] = [];
dataParaGrafica = Object.assign(dataParaGrafica , dataOriginalDB );
```

Estos últimos consumen menos recursos ya que el método de JSON.parse exige un poco mas al CPU, esto lo vas a notar si vas a estar convirtiendo arreglos grande (>30k registros).

Espero te sirva, saludos!